# TTS Accessibility for Commercial Mobile Alert System (CMAS) Messages

Tags: text-to-speech, accessibility

This applies to Android users in the USA.

Has anyone received a [CMAS message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Mobile_Alert_System) (used for tornado warnings, etc.) with a TTS accessibility solution (i.e. Google Talkback, etc) enabled?

- Any recommendations based on positive, real-world experience, for a setup that would read the message at the time it is received? (Android Version, Phone, TTS Solution, etc.)

Rather than wait around till the next flash flood warning to test what works, I figured I'd check in here. If you can think of a better way to test this I'd be interested in that too. Thanks.

Comment: I've received a total of one CMAS message from my new phone.  That was enough for me to "Force stop" the app for good, having reviewed the level of rights given to it and combined with the idea that this is controlled by FEMA.  It was a bad idea, to be honest.